# What does 'ssh -L :8080:localhost:8080 root@test.abc.com' mean?

Tags: linux, ssh

Please can someone explain the following command

`ssh -L :8080:localhost:8080 root@test.abc.com`

Is it a ssh forward tunnel or reverse tunnel or port forwarding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should read

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 root@test.abc.com
```

Though the extra colon may be ignored and not cause a problem.

What this is saying is "open port 8080 on the ssk client machine and direct any traffic received to the ssh server on port 8080".

Once you have established a the ssh session, a tunnel will be created from the PC you are on to the server you are connecting to on port 8080 at both ends.

The first 8080 is the local port.

`localhost:8080` is the remote host and port that traffic received on local port 8080 should be directed to.  Note that it doesn't need to be the remote machine itself, it can be any machine that the server can access.

So yes this is a tunnel.

Comment: thanks, it is good answer. Do you know what's reason behind someone want to do this forward tunneling? it is strange that direct all the traffic to the localhost:8080...

Comment: This is usually done where there is a service that cannot be accessed directly because it is firewalled or has other restrictions.  It is used regularly.  In this case, if the remote host only allows access on port 22 (ssh), but the user wants to access a service listenin on 8080, the above command will let them access the service as if it were on their own machine on port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

It is a forward tunnel from port 8080 of the local machine to `localhost:8080` on `test.abc.com`.